# Geoserver - long "busy" state

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, windows, tomcat

I've install Geoserver into Tomcat server 8.5, and since I've published new layer from PostGis data source, Geoserver show this message:

```
Server is currently busy. Please wait...
```

How can I stope it or fix it? On my server running Windows.

Comment: what do the logs show?

Comment: I can not see ... when I click to logs, I have also this message.

Comment: Do you know if the latest versions already have correction?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144377)

Answer (score 2):

You get that message if a long running REST POST/PUT request is running, or if another admin is running on the UI a long operation, such as computing the bounding box of a very large database layer.

There is no way to make it go away right now, the underlying configuration data structures are not thread safe for modification and the lock you see is preventing them from being ruined.

Future versions of GeoServer will have a thread safe configuration and  shorter lived locks, if you are interested in having this sooner you should consider sponsoring this feature via a commercial support provider:
http://geoserver.org/support/

(I've already implemented the thread safe part for 2.11 in my spare time, so implementing a smarter locking primitive is the only missing bit now)

Comment: Up to 2023: no progress on this issue ? I am experiencing it systematically with a 29GB pyramidal tile set. Every single time I try to create a layer, I get the issue.
Also, it seems that geoserver never exits this state, and I do have to restart it completely (which breaks existing jobs) !?

Comment: No one stepped up to do it or sponsor it, so far. Contrary to my initial optimistic assessment, locking is not enough, a transaction manager is required. If you are interested in getting anything done in GeoServer see https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-fixes,-improvements-and-new-features-in-GeoServer

Comment: I wish I was left with more time to try and improve this, geoserver is a pretty amazing piece of software. Meanwhile, I was wondering how a full-blown second instance of the server might pre-process the data, and how we could fast-forward it to the production server...